# Como transformar Json em objeto com campos dinamicos usando o Gson no Android?

Tags: android, json

Tenho o seguinte json:

> {"Data" :{ "Descricao":  "app", "Campo2": "app2", "Campo3": "app3"}, "InString" : "1", "Token" : "ZoebarW9NiMk9O"}

O campo "Data" pode conter 1:N campos.

Para exemplificar, tentei montar a seguinte estrutura de classe:

```
class JsonDynamicData {
        Map<String, String> info;
    }

    class JsonDynamicClass {

        JsonDynamicData Data;
        int inString;
        String token;           

        public JsonDynamicClass() {
            Data = new JsonDynamicData();
        }
    }

    private void jsonDinamico() {
        //TODO
        try {

            String json = IOUtils.toString(getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsonmoredata));

            JsonDynamicClass toJson = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonDynamicClass.class);                

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

Porém a conversão do Json para meu objeto não funcionou.

Como devo proceder pra criar uma estrutura de objeto em que o campo "Data" possa receber 1:N campos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É necessário utilizar [**Gson**](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

Pois o Android tem o [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), que já faz algo similar ao que você quer, transformando a string `JSON`, em um objeto de tuplas, você pode fazer algo similar a isso:

```java
String str = "{'nome': 'Fernando', 'idade': 25}";
JSONObject json;
try {
    json = new JSONObject(str);
    int idade = json.getInt("idade");
    String nome = json.getString("nome");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

O [**Gson**](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), do Google, é ótimo, para utilizar quando seu `JSON`, corresponde a uma `class` de modelo do seu projeto, já que ele consegue fazer toda essa conversão para você. No seu caso me parece ser mais apropriado utilizar o [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) mesmo.